# MFC doc/view architecture - create document without initial view

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, visual-studio-2003, document-view

I'm transferring some old C++ code from an old build environment (VS2003) to a (slightly) newer one (VS2010) - a newer IDE is not appropriate for various reasons. I'm trying to build it with as few changes as I can manage.

It loads up a set of views from a saved file. What I notice is that when built on VS2010, there's always one extra view. I conclude that this version of MFC must create an initial view, whereas the old one didn't.

I suppose having loaded them all I could remove the unwanted view, but I am wondering if there is a tidier way in getting it not to create the unwanted view in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

look at some `NewDocument()` call in the application initialization class. Probably you mix some old code with the one generated by the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I case that you have an MDI app, between

```
// Parse command line for standard shell commands, DDE, file open
CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);
```

and

```
// Dispatch commands specified on the command line
if(! ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
    return FALSE;
```

you should simply put:

```
// suppress automatic creation of child window
if(CCommandLineInfo::FileNew == cmdInfo.m_nShellCommand)
    cmdInfo.m_nShellCommand = CCommandLineInfo::FileNothing;
```

and on startup, you will not have a new view/doc.